# Popup windows are behind window but it is rendered front?

Tags: c++, windows, webkit, popup, user-input

I am updating the webkit embeded to my program however I come across a new problem about popup windows (MessageBox or File/Folder chooser dialogs).

For instance, if I invoke a javascript alert() clicking on a link, the MessageBox is rendered in front of the webkit window and looks like it is clickable, however when it is clicked the webkit window gain the focus and the MessageBox goes back of the webkit window. After that everything works as usual.

This problem does not happens if I invoke the alert() with keyboard.

So given the clues, what could be the solution, any tips ?

OS: Win7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In win/webview.cpp WM_CANCELMODE message invokes a function. Comment out, problem is solved.